# How do I get the request data that caused an ASP .NET error

Tags: .net, sql-server, error-handling

I am working on an ASP.NET application on SQL Server 2008. Sometimes users generate errors on the site for various reasons and it would be really useful if I could get the original request that generated the error so that I could replay it or make it part of a test.

I am familiar with the Event viewer to look up an error but I find that the summaries don't give me enough information like "What was the special character they tried to use"?

Is this possible? How would I find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not default way to do this as far as I know. You will have to add additional logging to your application that will allow you to catch this info and store it in a database or send it to admin via email.

Try modifying Application_Error method in Global.asax

Here is how to gather some info there and you can modify this further to suite your needs

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    // At this point we have information about the error
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    Exception exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();

    //Error message that will be emailed
    string errorInfo =
        "<br><b>Time:</b> " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
        "<br><b>Offending URL:</b> " + ctx.Request.Url.ToString() +
        "<br><b>Referring URL:</b> " + ctx.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() +
        "<br><br><b>Query String:</b> " + ctx.Request.QueryString.ToString() +
        "<br><br><b>IP Address:</b> " + ctx.Request.UserHostAddress +
        "<br><br><b>Form:</b> " + ctx.Request.Form.ToString() +
        "<br><br><b>Source:</b> " + exception.Source +
        "<br><br><b>Message:</b> " + exception.Message +
        "<br><br><b>Stack trace:</b> " + exception.StackTrace;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have to try it out. Do you know if there is a performance impact?

Comment: Hi @Herbert I am trying to send the error in an email like `<%@ Application Language="C#" %><%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Helpers" %>..WebMail.Send("help@gmale.com", subject: "Application error", body: errorInfo, from: "NOTIFICATIONS@gmale.co.uk", isBodyHtml: true);` but it's not working. I have tried debugging it in VStudio and it runs but I don't get an email

Comment: Peter, your new issue is separate and should be asked in a new question. However, I notice that in one line you are using "help@gmale.com" then in another you are using "NOTIFICATIONS@gmale.co.uk" make sure that you are using the correct domain.

Comment: I didn't realise it until a few weeks ago but it is working. Perhaps I needed to restart IIS. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Elmah error logging. It is free and able to handle error well and it show a lot useful information. You can configure it to send email when error occurred.

URL:
https://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: Thanks for your response Vincent. I have looked at Elmah before but I have had problems setting it up - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156791/elmah-on-iis-6-not-logging-errors